# Use grep or other to tidify the output of 7z -l

Tags: grep, 7-zip

I need to get the root directories of a compound file on a linux system. 
For this, i tried to use 7zip (p7zip-full) since this tool can read the compound file format.

This basically works great, but it outputs an horrible parsable text.

http://pastebin.com/VP4ZW8jr

So my question to the community is, is there a chance to get this output parsed nicely to get an output like:

- IPC_0805_CHIP_CAP
- FileHeader
- Library
- ZForm
- DO-214AA
- ...

?

I need this information inside of a php script. 
so at the end, the command will be executed from a php script. 
If there is any chance to read the compound file structure directly with php, this would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's some output there, and 7z doesn't seem to have much in the way of format options. I wouldn't want to try just grep, but a combination of head, tail & cut should work well enough to output just the filenames, and similar cuts should work for the other info, `tee` and process substitution ( `<()` ) could help. Or just cut each line by characters with php (I'm not familiar enough with it).

With my 7zr version, it has 18 lines of non-filename info at the start, and 2 lines at the end, with each line having 54 non-filename characters at the start, adjust if yours is different:

```
$ 7zr l test.7z  |tail -n+18|head -n-2|cut -c54-
file1
file2
file3
```